# how to connect external database with joomla website on wamp server

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla, connectivity

i am beginer with joomla cms and unable to connect joomla site with my wamp server database, i found every time this error...Serever error
here is my configuration file, i think my $log_path is wrong
my site name: livesite
database name: livesite

```
<?php
class JConfig {
    var $offline = '0';
    var $editor = 'tinymce';
    var $list_limit = '20';
    var $helpurl = 'http://help.joomla.org';
    var $debug = '0';
    var $debug_lang = '0';
    var $sef = '1';
    var $sef_rewrite = '1';
    var $sef_suffix = '0';
    var $feed_limit = '10';
    var $feed_email = 'author';
    var $secret = '6UmRx1LGrZq3Hr5X';
    var $gzip = '0';
    var $error_reporting = '-1';
    var $xmlrpc_server = '0';
    var $log_path = '/wamp/www/livesite/logs';
    var $tmp_path = '/wamp/www/livesite/tmp';
    var $live_site = '';
    var $force_ssl = '0';
    var $offset = '0';
    var $caching = '0';
    var $cachetime = '15';
    var $cache_handler = 'file';
    var $memcache_settings = array();
    var $ftp_enable = '0';
    var $ftp_host = '';
    var $ftp_port = '';
    var $ftp_user = '';
    var $ftp_pass = '';
    var $ftp_root = '';
    var $dbtype = 'mysql';
    var $host = 'localhost';
    var $user = 'root';
    var $db = 'livesite';
    var $dbprefix = 'table_prefix_';
    var $mailer = 'smtp';
    var $mailfrom = 'noreply@softwaretop100.org';
    var $fromname = 'SoftwareTop100';
    var $sendmail = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
    var $smtpauth = '0';
    var $smtpsecure = 'none';
    var $smtpport = '25';
    var $smtpuser = '';
    var $smtppass = '';
    var $smtphost = 'localhost';
    var $MetaAuthor = '1';
    var $MetaTitle = '1';
    var $lifetime = '50';
    var $session_handler = 'database';
    var $password = '';
    var $sitename = 'livesite';
    var $MetaDesc = 'Lists, research and news about the software industry, including the top list of the world’s largest software companies.';
    var $MetaKeys = 'software, top software, applications, software companies, top, news, it companies, software industry, software news, it news, software jobs, jobs, software research, information, software information, list, forum, software forum';
    var $offline_message = 'This site is down for maintenance. Please check back again soon.';
}
?>
```

Comment: $log_path has nothing to do with DB, you need to check $dbtype,$host,$user,$db and $password. What's the error you get, anyway?

Comment: sir i got Internet server error, actually i have to change joomla verion for my website..and unable to make connection with database....

Comment: @user2123036 check your credentials plus log and temp path correctly set or not..also check for any WHITESPACE occurred accidentally

Comment: $dbtype,$host,$user,$db and $password, i checked these many time, there is no error ....

Comment: $log_path = '/wamp/www/livesite/logs'; var $tmp_path = '/wamp/www/livesite/tmp';

Comment: @user2123036 just try with the path that i mentioned in answer and let me know then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you login credentials are correct, try with this and let me know then -

```
var $log_path = 'C:\\wamp\\www\\livesite\\logs';
var $tmp_path = 'C:\\wamp\\www\\livesite\\tmp';
```